# MySQL: Generate Autokey but use same for multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that stores a mapping from an ID to a set of values:

```
CREATE TABLE `mapping` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Value` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This table is a list of values and the ID of a row selects the set, this value belongs to.
So the column ID is unique per set, but not unique per row.

I insert data into the table using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO `mapping`
SELECT 5, `value` FROM `set1`;
```

In this example I calculated and set the ID manually to 5.
It would be great if mysql could set this ID automatically. I know the autokey feature, but using it will not work, because all rows inserted with the same insert statement should have the same ID.

So each insert statement should generate a new ID and then use it for all inserted rows.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not convinced to it (I'm not sure whether [locking table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) is good idea, I think it's not), but this might help:

```
lock tables `mapping` as m write, m as m1 read;

insert into m
select (select max(id) + 1 from m1), `value` from `set1`;

ulock tables;
```

Comment: Is the table locking necessary? I think the touched indices (and the index gap at the end) should be locked by innodb automatically when using transaction isolation level REPEATABLE_READ

Comment: Ah and just another question - is it possible to return this ID to my application? When using the autokey feature, I can request the last inserted ID. But with max()? Or do I have to use two separate statements in a transaction, one selecting the max(id) and the other inserting the values?

Comment: @Heinzi `lock` is to be sure that no other session do a `select (max)` part for its own `insert`. Maybe I'm paranoid :-), but anyway way I don't think that locking is a good idea :-). I've corrected a code a little.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have an additional table with an autogenerated key on single rows.  Insert (with or without an necessary or appropriate other data) into that table, thus generating the new ID, and then use the generated key to insert into the mapping table.

This moves you to a world where the non-unique id is a foreign key reference to a truly unique key.  Much more in keeping with typical relational database thinking.